# vscode: pasting autocomplete with return key sometimes doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode often suggests symbols as you type e.g. a variable or field name. When the correct variable name is suggested, usually I can press return to paste the suggestion.

This used to work all the time, now it only works *often*. And it's driving my crazy. Now, sometimes, when I press return, it actually enters a return character instead of the selected symbol.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Relevant info:

- I'm writing rust, with the popular [rust-anayzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) extension.
- I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Not sure what I should google for, or where to look for potential problems.

Comment: Add version info for your rust instalation components and what version of the VS Code rust-analyzer extension you are on. Have you made any changes to your VS Code's `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` setting? If so, what did you set it to?

Comment: Related GitHub issues: [Suggestions box's first choice is sometimes selected, sometimes NOT #173387](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173387). And these closed as a dupe of the previous one: [Pressing enter to apply does not apply completion #173343](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173343) and [Issue when pressing enter key to apply suggestion. #173903](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173903). Does that first one cover your issue?